# How can I get to add images to html5 code

Tags: html, html5-img

I'm trying add the images to html5 code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> trying the code </title>
<body>
<h1> html code </h1>
<img src="YOUniverse-swati1.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It takes more time to ask this question here instead searching fast just 2 words: html images. Don't mind but you can solve your problem fast without waiting here those primitive answers.

Comment: ok...tq for the suggestion. @StangaciuGeorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by using the `<img>` tag -
For Example-

```
<img src="nature.jpg" alt="Nature" />
```

Just make sure that the image name is correct & is placed in the same folder.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Satnam Singh